# Cookies duplicating with Internet Explorer (Node backend)

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, cookies

I've got an Angular application with a Node/Express backend. I just tested it in Internet Explorer (11) and noticed a strange bug with the authentication.

At some point I update the authentication details, which are stored in a Json Web Token in a cookie. On chrome, I simply set a new cookie with the same name, and it works fine. However, with IE I found it didn't use the new cookie, and found it had actually stored two:

[image]

Both have the same name. They're both provided by the same code, on the same domain (though we do have a second subdomain hosted, it's nothing to do with this site).

Setting the cookie is simply:

```
response.cookie('jwt', token, { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 48 * 1000, httpOnly: true });
```

using cookie-parser.

All the other questions seem to suggest this is issues with sub-domains. But I can't see how to specify/set it?

It works fine hosted locally in development, but when deployed in production shows this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by explicitely setting the domain of the cookie when set, rather than leaving it blank.

However, since Internet Explorer seemed to completely ignore cookies on `localhost`, I had to set add the line:

```
127.0.0.1    mydevdomain.com
```

to the windows host file at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.

I could then set cookies with the option: `domain: 'mydevdomain.com'` and it behaved as expected in development and when in production (updating the domain to the production domain).